# Kivy animations in a loop

Tags: python, loops, kivy, kivy-language

So I have a program that creates a bunch of KivyMD cards based on some data stored in a sql database. The MDCards are created and then added and that part of the program loops till there is no more cards to add. I wanted to make the cards fade in one by one when they are being added so I animated the opacity property of the cards and placed that in the loop. But the cards get animated together as if they are one  object. Here is the code for that part

```
def load_list_entries(self):
    mycursor.execute(Remainder_selection)
    self.remainders = mycursor.fetchall()
    self.remainders_amount = len(self.remainders)
    Mainscreenvar = sm.get_screen("MainScreen")
    sep = 0
    for i in range(self.remainders_amount):
        self.remainder = MDCard(size = (Window.width - Window.width/10, '100dp'),
                                size_hint = (None, None),
                                color_bg = (0,0,0,0.5),
                                opacity = 0,
                                radius = (20,20,20,20),
                                pos_hint = {"center_x": .5},
                                pos = (0,str(-sep) + "dp"),
                                padding = (10,10,10,10),
                                name = str(self.remainders[i][0])
                           )
        self.remainder.bind(on_release = self.callback_function)
        self.element1 = RelativeLayout(size = self.remainder.size,
                                       )
        self.element2 = Label(text = self.remainders[i][1],
                              text_size = self.element1.size,
                              color = (1,1,1,1) if ThemeManager.theme_style == "Dark" else (0,0,0,1),
                              valign = "top",
                              padding = ("20dp","20dp"),
                              font_name = "Roboto-Black",
                              font_size = "30sp",
                              shorten = True,
                              shorten_from = "right", 
                           )
        self.element3 = Label(text = self.remainders[i][2],
                              text_size = self.element1.size,
                              color = (1,1,1,0.6) if ThemeManager.theme_style == "Dark" else (0,0,0,0.6),
                              padding = ("20dp","20dp"),
                              font_name = "Roboto-Regular",
                              font_size = "13sp",
                              shorten = True,
                              shorten_from = "right")
        sep = sep + self.remainder.height + 10
        self.element1.add_widget(self.element2)
        self.element1.add_widget(self.element3)
        self.remainder.add_widget(self.element1)
        Mainscreenvar.ids.Remaindercontainer.add_widget(self.remainder)
        anim1 = Animation(opacity = 1)
        anim1.start(self.remainder)
```

The actual animation part is the last few lines. My belief was that first I would create one card, add all the necessary parts to it and then add the card to the screen and then finally animate that one card appearing and then repeat the process once again from the beginning for the next card. But the entire animation part takes place in one go. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My belief was that first I would create one card, add all the necessary parts to it and then add the card to the screen and then finally animate that one card appearing and then repeat the process once again from the beginning for the next card.

This is wrong, anim1.start is not blocking so there is no gap between starting the animation and instantiating/adding the next widgets.

Instead of using a loop, bind to the `on_complete` even of the animation a function that runs your next task. This will let the animation finish and *then* run your next piece of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea. But my program requires the use of a loop as I do not know how many times I must run that loop and how many MDCards I need to create. That data is provided by the databases. So is there any other way that I can do this?Thanks for the help

Comment: Your program does not require that loop. You need to write code that performs things with the timing you want, as I described. For instance, you could query the database to get a list of parameters for making your cards, then use `Clock.schedule_once` each time the animation runs to create the next one from the list, until the list is empty.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks a lot!